# Why is the temporary variable necessary when allocating?

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *textField;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textField;

UITextField *aTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];   
self.textField = aTextField;
[aTextField release];
```

I don't know why `aTextField` is necessary. Can't I write it like this?

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UITextField *textField;

self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UITextField *textField;

self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
```

From comment on @bbum answer:

> I didn't retain. I assinged in property. Retain count is 1 after
>   assignment. I just need release one time in dealloc.

**Don't do this!**

Ok, that wouldn't leak if nothing happened in between (the property is `assign`!) but this goes against the basics of *Object Ownership*.

The properties marked as `assign` are used for objects **you don’t own**, e.g., delegates. Therefore, according to the *Memory Management Rules*: **You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own.**

By doing this, you will get into lots of trouble because you are relying on an implementation detail, the fact that you know that you created the object and you need to release it. You do not want to put yourself in that position. What if you later set another object? You would leak the former and probably over-release the later, leading to a potential crash.

Comment: Is it ok if I use like this? textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];

Comment: I would only access the ivar directly in initializers and `dealloc`. I would go through the property accessor elsewhere. Anyway `textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];` is ok as long as you release any previous object that `textField` may point to.

Comment: You are welcome. p.s: what is it that you don't know fully? I can try to explain better :)

Answer (score 5):

Clarification:  **Think of retains and releases as deltas;  for every statement that implies a retain, you must have a balancing release.   A retain is a statement of "keep this object alive until the balancing release".**

Almost;  you'd need (assuming `@property(retain) UITextField *textField;`):

```
 textField = [[UITextField alloc] init]; // +1 retain
```

Or:

```
 self.textField = [[[UITextField alloc] init] autorelease]; // +1, +1, -1 (delayed)
```

The only difference being that the above is a direct assignment and does not use the setter to retain the object.

If you were to do:

```
 self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] init]; // +1 +1
```

You'd leak the object.

And, yes, in all correct cases, you need to either:

```
self.textField = nil;
```

Or:

```
[textField release];
```

In your `dealloc`.

---

Oh -- I'm sorry -- I missed the `assign` on that second `@property` declaration.

In short, don't do that.  It is a weak reference and can easily become dangling.  It has its uses and, sadly, they are more common than they should be (bank pointers in object graphs, most commonly, though delegates use 'em too).   What I wrote above still stands;  consider retains as a delta and, in the case of `assign`, there is no +1 and nothing to balance.

But, in this case, `assign` is also most likely incorrect;  you'd want `retain`.  You *could* use `assign` and manage the retain/release externally, but that is both atypical and rife with fragility.  `retain` on properties exists specifically to express ownership!

Comment: I will do release in dealloc.

Comment: Does it have problem even if I release in dealloc?

Comment: I didn't retain. I assinged in property. Retain count is 1 after assignment. I just need release one time in dealloc. I still don't understand.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign) is what I wrote in the second part.

Comment: @user698200 if you mark the property as `assign`, you do not own the object and according to the *Memory Management Rules*: **You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own**. "I just need release one time in dealloc" If you did this, you would be relying on an implementation detail and you do not want to put yourself in that position.

Comment: @user698200 Don't look at the retain count!